# Neural Network for binary classification not working

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, python-3.x

I have made a neural network that was working correctly as a multi-class classifier, but after changing the loss and the activation function, plus the output layer to just 1 neuron, it is not working correctly. I hope you can tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
    # Define the MLP model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1], input_dim= X_train.shape[1], activation= 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2*X_train.shape[1], activation= 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2*X_train.shape[1],activation= 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation= 'sigmoid', kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, 
                        verbose=1, mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)


# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test),callbacks=[monitor], epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=1)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred_classes = y_pred

y_preds = np.argmax(y_pred_classes, axis=1)

# Calculate and print accuracy
accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, y_preds)
print('Accuracy of MLP: ' + str(accuracy))

# Calculate and print precision, recall, and F1-score
precision, recall, fscore, _ = precision_recall_fscore_support(Y_test, y_preds, average='weighted')
print('Precision of MLP: ' + str(precision))
print('Recall of MLP: ' + str(recall))
print('F1-score of MLP: ' + str(fscore))

# Print the classification report and confusion matrix
print(classification_report(Y_test, y_preds,target_names=target_names))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
cm=confusion_matrix(Y_test,y_preds)
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True,cmap='Blues',linewidth=0.5,fmt=".0f",ax=ax,xticklabels=target_names, yticklabels=target_names)
plt.xlabel("Predicted")
plt.ylabel("Real")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You validation accuracy is high. There are many potential factors involved, e.g. leakage of the training data into the validation data that makes the validation accuracy artificially high, different distribution of the validation and test sets (e.g. different class imbalances), etc.

Comment: Hello noe. The problem is that the network used worked correctly doing a multi-class classification. I have just changed the last neuron, the activation function of the last layer and the loss function. As you can see in the code I am using X_train and X_test, which I have split after preprocessing and oversampling. Also, in the confussion matrix, you can see, obviously a 2x2 matrix, and the results for 'Attack' class is 0. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Why *should* it work? Perhaps it would help for you to explain this explanation.

Comment: It has been working correctly for multi-class classifiaction, i guess it shouldn't have any problem working as a binary classifier. I have tried different architectures for an MLP and all have a 0.9929 accuracy and around .9860 precision. I also tried with an LSTM network and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred_classes = y_pred
y_preds = np.argmax(y_pred_classes, axis=1)
```

Your model outputs a single value (`Dense(1,activation= 'sigmoid', kernel_initializer='normal')`)

If `n_test` is the number of items in `X_test`, your output `y_pred` will be of size `(n_test, 1)`.

When you call `y_preds = np.argmax(y_pred_classes, axis=1)`, you argmax along a unit dimension, so you just get a vector of 0s.

You need to instead set a threshold and determine predictions by `y_pred_classes = y_pred > threshold`